# 2 layout файла ровно посередине любого экрана

Tags: android

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы на любом смартфоне Android 2 layout (Linear и relative, если это важно) были ровно посередине? 
Пишу программу, которой необходимо, чтобы оба layout были ровно посередине (на верхнем - фото, на нижнем - иконки и ссылки).
Как это сделать? И, если это невозможно, есть ли аналог, позволяющий добиться такого эффекта?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделение экрана пополам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/447051/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc). Для того, чтобы дополнить вопрос - редактируйте существующий (ссылка-кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не задавайте новый, точно такой-же с добавленной картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Используй атрибут `gravity` c параметром `center` для всех компонентов внутри лэйаутов. Но чтобы ответить точнее составь примерную разметку экрана, какие компоненты на нем должны быть, так будет проще понять и самому

Comment: Вот здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/447051/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC я уточнил вопрос. Можете мне помочь разобраться?