# Разделение экрана пополам

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы `LinearLayout` был ВСЕГДА (на всех экранах) посередине `RelativeLayout`? 
Суть в том, что иконки, которые на `LinearLayout`, должны располагаться ровно посередине фото, которое находится на `RelativeLayout`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы два контейнера делили экран пополам по горизонтали (две равные половинки)  или чтобы кнопки внутри нижнего контейнера были отцентрованы по вертикали? Во втором случае нужно ценровать элементы внутри контейнера, а не сам контейнер относительно другого.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы два контейнера делили экран пополам. Кнопки внутри нижнего контейнера уже отцентрованы другим LinearLayout.

Comment: Фотогрфия должна быть на весь экран, а кнопки в нижней половине что ли? или половина экрана фото и половина кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <!-- Остальной контент -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

RelativeLayout является корневым элементом, в котором `view` элементы можно располагать любым образом относительно других `view`, либо привязывать к определенным сторонам `RelativeLayout`. Для того, чтобы привязать `view` к середине `RelativeLayout` необходимо параметр `android:layout_centerInParent` установить в `true`. По умолчанию элементы в `RelativeLayout` привязываются к верхнему левому краю.

UPD: пример расположения элементов с данной разметкой
[image: расположение элементов]

Comment: @pavloff, а если вместо LinearLayout на моем экране сделать 2 RelativeLayout и применить к ним параметр android:layout_centerInParent , 2 RelativeLayout в итоге будут посередине любого экрана?

Comment: @pavloff, спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Все получилось, но теперь возник другой вопрос. Есть ли возможность изменять размер иконок? Имею в виду, при разных разрешениях чтобы иконка и подпись к ней занимала бОльшую часть экрана. А то получается ситуация, что на некоторых телефонах иконки выглядят большими и их комфортно нажимать, а на некоторых - очень маленькими и их неудобно нажимать. Как я понимаю, тут необходимо использовать все тот же атрибут "вес"?У меня следующая компоновка: горизонтальный Linear, в который вложен вертикальный Linear,а в него уже иконка и подпись к ней. Сможете помочь?

Comment: @user186295 Это не мой ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, для простого размещения двух элементов на разметке компоновщик `RelativeLayout` избыточен, он гораздо "тяжелее" `LinearLayout` и будет потреблять ресурс без толку.

Для пропорционального разделения пополам (часть экрана занимает один элемент, а часть -другой) можно использовать указание "весов" элементов - атрибут `android:layout_weight`, который указывает какую часть экрана занимать определенному элементу - в данной разметке две равные части по 50 процентов каждая (высота при использовании "веса" элемента указывается `0dp`, так как в вычислении не участвует):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Расчет пропорций при использовании весов производится следующим образом: все указанные в разметке веса складываются (в нашем случае 50+50) и это число принимается равным всей высоте (ширине) экрана - 100% . Отдельные элементы занимают такое количество места, которое будет процентом указанного веса для элемента по отношению к всей сумме (В нашем случае у каждого по 50 - значит разделится на равные части).

Сами указанные числа не влияют на распредение, а только их процентное соотношение к сумме всех весов. То есть точно такой же результат получится, если указать веса каждому элементу по 0.5, к примеру. Или, чтобы разделить экран один к трем, то можно указать одному вес равный 1, другому равный 2 - сумма будет равна трем и первый элемент будет треть экрана, а второй две трети.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если надо именно Relative - поместить в центр вьюху с нулевым размером и центровать относительно неё.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?